# C++ template function, inheritance, shared_ptr

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I guess this is a very basic question but I'm still asking because I suspect the compiler acts as expected and the error rather comes from me!

I'd like to implement an abstract class with a template abstract function. As you may know, that's not possible: a template function cannot be abstract.

So I have to implement a dummy function in my base class.
Inconvenient for many reasons, but so be it.

The problem is that, as soon as I'm using pointers, the compiler calls the base class function, not the child class implementation.

How to solve this ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Person
{
  protected:
    std::string _first_name;
    std::string _last_name;

  public:
    Person(std::string first_name, std::string last_name):
        _first_name(first_name), _last_name(last_name){}

    const std::string & first_name() const { return _first_name; }
    const std::string & last_name() const { return _last_name; }
};

// ==============================================================================
// Using template functions.

class HumanPrinterBase
{
  public:
    template <typename T>
    void print(const T & person) const { std::cout << "HumanPrinterBase::print()" << std::endl; }
};

class HumanFirstNamePrinter : public HumanPrinterBase
{
  public:
    template <typename T>
    void print(const T & person) const
    {
        std::cout << person.first_name() << std::endl;
    }
};


// ==============================================================================
// Using non-template functions.

class PersonPrinterBase
{
  public:
    virtual ~PersonPrinterBase() = default;
    virtual void print(const Person & person) const = 0;
};

class PersonFirstNamePrinter : public PersonPrinterBase
{
  public:
    virtual void print(const Person & person) const override
    {
        std::cout << person.first_name() << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Person person("John", "Doe");

    std::unique_ptr<HumanPrinterBase> hp = std::make_unique<HumanFirstNamePrinter>();
    hp->print(person); // "HumanPrinterBase::print()" (fails)

    std::unique_ptr<PersonPrinterBase> pp = std::make_unique<PersonFirstNamePrinter>();
    pp->print(person); // "John" (works)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No for dynamic polymorphism to work you need an abstract baseclass with virtual functions not a template classs (static polymorphism). Your `HumanPrinterBase` should have a pure virtual function (and virtual destructor) : `virtual void print(const PersonBase& person) = 0;`  (where PersonBase is another pure abstract base class)

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is CRTP, but this problem is so over-engineered that it's hard to guess what is the actual problem being solved and what conditions should solution satisfy.

Comment: There are ways to do this with templates only (static polymorphism) but that would not involve inheritance at all (except maybe as @Yksisarvinen says CRTP to mixin reusable code). Also be careful when using std::shared_ptr it should not be your first choice (I mosly only use it in multithreading scenarios)

Comment: This is similar to [Double Dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) but the addition of a template would throw a wrench in the normal solutions.

Comment: But Pepijn is right. `HumanFirstNamePrinter` takes a `T` parameter, but then calls `person.first_name()`, which is a method of `Person`. So presumably it should simply take a non-template `const Person&` parameter.  Why does `print` need to be a template?

Comment: @MooingDuck `print` needs to be a template so that I can use this class to print anything that has a `first_name()` method.

Comment: @duncan: Make it accept a `const Named&` then.  `struct Named { virtual const std:string& first_name()=0; virtual ~Named(){} };`

Comment: I don't see how that would some the problem. Your solution implies that I could only use the `Printer` class only with classes that inherit from `Named`. I don't want all my classes to then inherit from `Named`! That's precisely the point of template: structural subtyping

Comment: How about a template printer object that thunks (forwards) to the template print function?  `struct PrinterBase { template <typename T> void print(T const& person) const { print_person(person); } };` and `template <typename T> void print_person(T const& person) { cout << person.first_name() << "\n"; }`

Comment: There is a good reason why there are no virtual function templates. They are fundamentally impossible given the C++ template compilation model. If there existed a workaround, there would be no such restriction in the first place. The compiler would just implement the workaround.

Comment: Yes, I figured... Still that's a serious limitation... On one hand we have concepts that allow powerful structural subtyping, on the other hand, you cannot use those inside classes... For an object-oriented language, that's so frustrating...

Comment: C++ is not an object-oriented language. It is a multiparadigm language with some basic support for object-oriented programming.